# Manage image with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing an android app that using firebase. My app looks like

[image: app UI]

App shows card that contains image.
I don't know how to manage image when app works in offline mode.
Could you give me suggestion to resolve it ?

Comment: Show some code, what have you tried?

Comment: I didn't  implement. I have just defined GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, use offline capabilities of Firebase by using `.setPersistenceEnabled(true);`
2. Use a Image Managing Cloud Server like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) to store all your images.
3. In your Firebase database, save the Url to the image as a String.
4. Use a Image Library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to get your image from the url.

This worked for me, hope it helps you.

Comment: I found Android-Universal-Image-Loader. I am considering Picasso and Universal-Image-Loader. Do you have any idear ?

Comment: for fetching images from a server, I go for Picasso, but you can choose anything you like, both work like charm

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso or similar library for load image, show it and save in memory.

Use Firebase only for upload image to cloud and get link.

Example upload image:

```
 StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(app.packageName + ".webp");
        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(app.icon)));
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                success = false;
                countDown.countDown();
                Log.e(TAG, "", e);
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess");
                app.setPublicIconPath(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                ref.child(app.getFirebaseKey()).child("icon").setValue(app.getFirebaseValueDataPart1().getIcon());
            }
        });
```